# Gnome shell disable "glued" tiled windows

Tags: gnome3, tiling-wm

I often use tiled windows in GNOME, and it's great, but lately (I did not really notice when this started happening, I am running GNOME 3.26.2) I noticed a small change in behavior that I find really annoying: when two windows are tiled (one in the left half and the other in the right half), they are kind of "glued" together, and bringing one in the front will also bring the other in the front.

I wish to disable this behavior and being able to bring one window to front without having the other in the front as well.

The reason for this is that I often find myself with 3 windows in the workspace: a terminal window, maximized, and 2 windows with documentation. Since I use tmux in the terminal, I split the terminal window in there, and I do not tile the terminal, but I still want to bring a **single** documentation window on top, while having the terminal in the background.

Trying to make it clear, consider this is the window stack ("side-view")

```
+-----terminal-----+  (top/front)
+--doc1--++--doc2--+  (back, invisible)
```

I press meta key, go to overview, and select `doc1` window to bring it to front (or, more likely, I press Alt+Tab). What happens is:

```
+--doc1--++--doc2--+  (top/front)
+-----terminal-----+  (back, invisible)
```

but I wish that final result is

```
+--doc1--+            (top/front)
+-----terminal-----+  (middle, partially visible)
          +--doc2--+  (back, invisible)
```

How can I achieve this? I tried looking in dconf editor and tweak tools, but couldn't find anything related.